# Text processing to get if else type condition from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-parsing, text-processing

First of all, I am sorry about the weird question heading. Couldn't express it in one line.

So, the problem statement is,

If I am given the following string --

`"('James Gosling'/jamesgosling/james gosling) , ('SUN Microsystem'/sunmicrosystem), keyword"`

I have to parse it as

`list1 = ["'James Gosling'", 'jamesgosling', 'jame gosling']`

`list2 = ["'SUN Microsystem'", 'sunmicrosystem']`

`list3 = [ list1, list2, keyword]`

So that, if I enter `James Gosling Sun Microsystem keyword` it should tell me that what I have entered is ***100% correct***

And if I enter `J Gosling Sun Microsystem keyword` it should say i am only ***66.66% correct.***

***This is what I have tried so far.***

```
import re

def main():
    print("starting")
    sentence = "('James Gosling'/jamesgosling/jame gosling) , ('SUN Microsystem'/sunmicrosystem), keyword"
    splited = sentence.split(",")
    number_of_primary_keywords = len(splited)
    #print(number_of_primary_keywords, "primary keywords length")
    number_of_brackets = 0
    inside_quotes = ''
    inside_quotes_1 = ''
    inside_brackets = ''
    for n in range(len(splited)):
        #print(len(re.findall('\w+', splited[n])), "length of splitted")
        inside_brackets = splited[n][splited[n].find("(") + 1: splited[n].find(")")]
        synonyms = inside_brackets.split("/")
        for x in range(len(synonyms)):
            try:
                inside_quotes_1 = synonyms[x][synonyms[x].find("\"") + 1: synonyms[n].find("\"")]
                print(inside_quotes_1)
            except:
                pass
            try:
                inside_quotes = synonyms[x][synonyms[x].find("'") + 1: synonyms[n].find("'")]
                print(inside_quotes)
            except:
                pass
            #print(synonyms[x])
        number_of_brackets += 1

    print(number_of_brackets)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Output is as follows***

```
'James Gosling

jamesgoslin

jame goslin

'SUN Microsystem
SUN Microsystem
sunmicrosyste
sunmicrosyste
3
```

As you can see, the last letters of some words are missing.

So, if you read this far, I hope you can help me in getting the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your code has a logic issue that I could not figure it out, however there might be in these lines:

```
inside_quotes_1 = synonyms[x][synonyms[x].find("\"") + 1: synonyms[n].find("\"")]
    
inside_quotes = synonyms[x][synonyms[x].find("'") + 1: synonyms[n].find("'")]
```

which by the way you can simply use:

```
inside_quotes_1 = synonyms[x][synonyms[x].find("\x22") + 1: synonyms[n].find("\x22")]
    
inside_quotes = synonyms[x][synonyms[x].find("\x27") + 1: synonyms[n].find("\x27")]
```

Other than that, you seem to want to extract the words with their indices, which you can extract them using a basic [expression](https://regex101.com/r/BuO5YV/1):

```
(\w+)
```

Then, you might want to find a simple way to locate the indices, where the words are. Then, associate each word to the desired indices.

[image]

#### Example Test

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "('James Gosling'/jamesgosling/james gosling) , ('SUN Microsystem'/sunmicrosystem), keyword"
expression = r'(\w+)'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911 ')
```